# Hola, Quisiera generar una variable que sea la media de alguna cosas en R y STATA

Tags: r, rstudio, stata

Estoy manejando una base de datos de los ingresos laborales de ciertos empleos quisiera generar una variable que sea la media de los ingresos laborales para cada según el empleo todo eso en un mismo vector como puedo hacerlo? quiero aprender hacerlo tanto en R como en STATA

Comment: Lo recomendable es mostrar un ejemplo. Muéstranos una parte de tus datos y en función a eso se te podrá ayudar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por respóndeme, mi intención es sacar la media de los ingresos laborales para cada tipo de empleo es decir  tengo una base de datos del mercado laboral y quiero que según el empleo de las personas me de la media de cada tipo de empleo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo.

Voy a crear un data frame en donde se tenga el empleo y los ingresos.

```
set.seed(10)
df<-data.frame(empleo=sample(c("EDUCACIÓN","BANCA","FINANZAS","TECNOLOGÍA","AGRICULTURA"), 1000,T),
               ingresos=sample(1000:10000, 1000,T))

head(df)
      empleo ingresos
1   FINANZAS     8705
2  EDUCACIÓN     1589
3      BANCA     3144
4 TECNOLOGÍA     3576
5   FINANZAS     9610
6      BANCA     2406
```

Entonces si tu deseas calcular los ingresos medios por empleo. Podrías hacer con r base con la función `aggregate()` con la siguiente sintaxis.

```
aggregate(ingresos~empleo, data = df, mean)

       empleo ingresos
1 AGRICULTURA 5690.068
2       BANCA 5383.436
3   EDUCACIÓN 5479.914
4    FINANZAS 5553.964
5  TECNOLOGÍA 5541.979
```

Con tidyverse se haría usando la función `group_by()` de la siguiente manera.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(empleo) %>% summarize(media=mean(ingresos))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  empleo      media
  <fct>       <dbl>
1 AGRICULTURA 5690.
2 BANCA       5383.
3 EDUCACIÓN   5480.
4 FINANZAS    5554.
5 TECNOLOGÍA  5542.
```

Y en `stata`tendrías que usar la función collapse, de la siguiente manera:

```
collapse (mean) ingresos, by(empleo)
```

Comment: Genial!!!! Muchas graciasss

Comment: Disculpe le pregunto algo usted sabe como presentar tablas de regresión en Stata o R Pero que sean estéticamente bonitas para poner en una presentación y exponer, es decir estoy corriendo un modelo de descomposición salarial y quiero que la tabla que me saque stata o R sea bonita para adjuntarla a una presentación en Powers point puede que la tabla sea una imagen o o que sea pero que sea estéticamente bonita